# Compare X number of items in Y number of lists and give them a qualification

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, linq, data-structures

Lets say I have `3 teams`, each team sits in a `group of 8` teams and I need to decide which team gets on which `position` in that group.

The combination of `team 1` on `position 1` and `team 2` on `position 1` gives `0 faults`,
but the combination of `team 1` on `position 1` and `team 2` on `position 2` gives a `fault of 2`

Now I need to find the best position for the teams depending on their faults. This is easy if it is only for 2 teams. But it gets harder when it is a X number of teams. Next to that is it possible to have positions that are already filled in the group so those positions cant be compared to each other.

For simplicity i only added a small example for a group of size 4 and size 8 but there are groups varying from 2 to 8 in size

For all these groupsizes i have the +- schema and i also have their faults calculated...

So for this example below i can put all teams at position 1
but it gets another story when in one of the groups position 1 is already taken.

I need to find the best possible option with the least amount of faults

### Background

[image]

**The groups look something like this... where null is an empty positions**

Some schema for calculation the faults
[image]

**Group of size 8**

[image]

**Group of size 4**

[image]

**The fault calculation**

We count a fault when the on position X == + and position Y == - or vice versa
If we find + == + or - == - for some positions then no fault

```
foreach (var teamAvailableLineNumberA in teamAvailableLineNumbers) {
      foreach (var availableLineNumberA in teamAvailableLineNumberA.Value) {
        foreach (var teamAvailableLineNumberB in teamAvailableLineNumbers) {
          if (teamAvailableLineNumberA.Key == teamAvailableLineNumberB.Key) { continue; } //Dont process yourself
          foreach (var availableLineNumberB in teamAvailableLineNumberB.Value) {
            var teamA = teamAvailableLineNumberA.Key;
            var teamB = teamAvailableLineNumberB.Key;

            var pmSchema = APlusMinusSchemas.Single(pm => pm.DrawSize == teamA.Group.GroupSize);
            var complementartyLine =pmSchema.LineNumbers[availableLineNumberA].ComplementaryLines.Single(cl => cl.DrawSize == teamB.Group.GroupSize && cl.LineNumber == availableLineNumberB);

            if (complementartyLine != null) {
              listOfComplementaryLinesByTeamCombination.Add(new Tuple<Team, Team, int, int, int>(teamA,teamB,availableLineNumberA, availableLineNumberB, complementartyLine.NumberOfFaultsHomeHome));
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

`teamAvailableLineNumbers = Dictionary<Team, List<int>>` where the `List<int>` is the available positions for the group its in.

How can I create an algorithm / datastructure that can calculate and hold this kind of information for a not known number of teams that has a not know number of available positions?

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: _each team sits in a `group of 8` teams_ I'm not sure what you mean - could you perhaps rephrase that? Maybe you could also give a short presentation of the data structures that you want to end up with, i.e. you are describing "position" in a "group" - what is that?

Comment: First It is not clear how faults relate to the positions of teams in a group. Second, what should decide the position of a team. You say the faults decide. But fault is just a number. What is the actual criterion? (Right now you just told us that the teams should be placed accoding to some value of some number -- that doesn't tell anything specific, isn't it?)

Comment: I would not be surprised that when you manage to come up with a detailed and specific explanation of what you want to achieve, you simultaneously would also have the blueprint of the code you should/could write...

Comment: it sounds like you are interested in something like "changing the number of loops at runtime", depending on that X, the number of teams. Maybe this answer that I posted recently on another question is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327140/finding-the-sum-of-common-elements-between-n-number-of-arrays-in-java/43332711#43332711

Comment: Tomorrow i Will try to explain in a better way

Comment: Hope this is enough background

Comment: @JordyvanEijk: to be honest I agree with elgonzo. I don't get the whole thing so I fell like I can't help you. The question is complex enough to provide more background.